# How to solve $y(x)=1+\int_0^x\left(\left(t+y(t)\right)^2-1\right)dt$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could you please help me to solve this equation:
$y(x)=1+\int_0^x\left(\left(t+y(t)\right)^2-1\right)dt$.

By differentiating I get first degree ODE:
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(x+y\right)^2-1$ and I could not solve it,
therefore I differentiated it again:
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2\left(x+y\right)\frac{dy}{dx}$ and I steal have no idea how to solve it.

Any hint would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint.

Take as a new function $z(x) = x+ y(x)$ then $z^\prime(x)=1+y^\prime (x)$.

Answer (score 2):

use a change of variable $$u = y + x, y = u - x, \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{du}{dx} - 1 $$ the initial value problem for $u$ is $$ \frac{du}{dx} - 1  = u^2-1, u = 1 , x = 0. \to \int_1^u \frac{du}{u^2} = x,1 - \frac 1u= x $$ that is $$u = \frac1{1-x}, \quad y = \frac{1}{1-x} - x=\frac{1-x+x^2}{1-x} $$